# Prevent Windows Subsystem for Android app windows from being resizable

Tags: android, windows, windows-subsystem-for-android

I would like the Windows Subsystem for Android application windows to feature fixed width and height, meaning they should be non-resizable. Certain apps encounter issues due to their lack of compatibility with window resizing. I am attempting to establish fixed sizes for the windows, akin to mirroring a cellphone screen on my PC. Ideally, all Windows Subsystem for Android application windows should initiate with the same predefined width and height.

I've tried through ADB, attempted to modify the WSA's AppxManifest.xml file. To be honest, I didn't know what I was doing. I have consulted both Microsoft's and Android's documentation regarding the resizing of applications, but I haven't achieved practical results.

How can I do this?